# Updating MOTD on login

Tags: login, motd

I've been tinkering with my CentOS server login procedure, I want to have my MOTD update using the [`linux_logo`](http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/) program. I've already tried doing this in a few ways, but didn't get the desired effect. I have started with this command:

```
/usr/bin/linux_logo -c -u -y -t "$R" > /etc/motd
```

The key info to be updated here is the uptime.

I have tried adding it to my `.bashrc` file, and adding the command to a new bash script in `/etc/profile.d/` folder, and making it executable. Both of these methods make it run at login, but only after the MOTD has been printed, so it's one login behind.

I also created an init script with the command in it using `chkconfig` to set it to start at runtime levels 345, this I believe just made it run the script during boot.

I have also tried adding the following to my `sshd_config` file:

```
ForceCommand /usr/bin/linux_logo -c -u -y -t "$R" > /etc/motd
```

This had the effect of closing my ssh connection every time I logged in :/

These were all suggestions from similar posts I found when googling for this, so I think I am missing something, at this point some help would be appreciated.

To summarise, I want the following, or similar command to run at login, prior to the motd being printed. Is this possible?

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/linux_logo ]; then
  /usr/bin/linux_logo -c -u -y -t "$R" > /etc/motd
fi
```

Comment: Why not just run it in a crontab every hour or so?

Comment: I suppose I could, I just thought this was a designed function of linux_logo, since it has a flag for showing the uptime of the server, why is it so difficult to use?

Comment: I don't see anything hard about adding a crontab. Do you know how to? It would be trivial to just run that command every few minutes and update your motd.

Comment: yeah I guess that's the sensible way to do it, I just thought it made more sense for it to be triggered at logon

I guess just adding it to crontab -e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to have this run when a user logs on, just add it to root's crontab or `/etc/crontab`. To run your command and update the motd every 5 minutes, add this line to `/etc/crontab`:

```
*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/linux_logo -c -u -y -t "$R" > /etc/motd
```

Comment: Yes, there are reasons to have things run when the user logs on. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett it answers this question, as you can see the OP accepted this answer. If you need something else, you can ask a new question, explaining what you need and why it needs to be run when the user logs on. Of course there are valid reasons to run things when a user logs on, but updating motd, which is what this question was about, isn't one of them, that's all.

Comment: The question is "Updating MOTD on login", this answer is for the question "Updating MOTD prior to login", which is a different question.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett I disagree, this is answering what the user really needed instead of what they asked and that is a very common thing here: we always try to answer the real question and not the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). But no worries, if you still disagree, downvote. That's how the sites work.

Comment: I'm here to find the answer to the question "Updating MOTD on login", which is the question at the top of this post. If you answer a different question, you make life more difficult for everyone else. If you want to answer a different question, open a new post with the correct question at the top.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett please ask a new question then. In _this_ case, the question was not really what is in the title, it was what is in the body and what is in the body does not require updating MOTD on login. This is what is known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). We always answer the actual question here, or at least try to, and don't just look at the title.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_%28Unix%29) the `/etc/motd` is called **before** it executes the login shell. That explains why including anything in the `.bashrc` file doesn't work.

Via `chkconfig` and links in `/etc/rcX.d/` the update is indeed only done at startup.

One thing you could try and look into is replace `/etc/motd` with a named pipe ( `mkfifo /etc/motd` ) and have a program somehow detect the reading from that pipe and  fill the pipe with the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

in modern linux, anything that will write to `/etc/motd.dynamic` will change login.

If you want to do it 'right', create `/etc/update-motd.d` and place scripts there whose output will compose the MOTD.

See

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/